# Does externalising react and react-dom dependencies give a gain in load time of a react app

Tags: reactjs, perf

I am working on react app. App load time is high. I want to reduce app load time by externalising dependencies for react and react-dom. Is this approach correct?

Answer (score 0):

React by itself usually doesn't add too much load time. [React-dom adds ~100k](https://bundlephobia.com/result?p=react-dom@16.12.0) and React is ~6kb.

Many libraries inside `package.json` do though. Code-splitting and lazy loading can help ([React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#code-splitting)) but in all honesty I feel they have their limits.

**Important to note though: are you measuring the size of the Production or the Development build?** The two vary considerably.

Benchmarks should always use the production build (if you use **create-react-app**, it would be `npm build`).

As websites grow in complexity, it's almost a fact that their load time will increase (Gmail was one of the first popular SPAs that had a considerate load time and even a progress bar for it!).

If you are very concerned about speed, server-side rendering or static rendering will greatly help, and you can even use it just to load your landing page. On 2018, [Airbnb moved to server-side rendering](https://medium.com/airbnb-engineering/operationalizing-node-js-for-server-side-rendering-c5ba718acfc9).

I am personally not a big fan of it mostly because I have grown used to higher loading times and our target audience doesn't mind so much, but I definitely vouch for it when needed.